# PHP MySQL Assign variables to array data

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following:

```
$sql="SELECT course_status, COUNT(course_name) FROM courses GROUP BY course_status";
```

Then a while loop to store the data:

```
$menu[] = array(
             'sum_status' => $row['COUNT(course_name)'],
             'course_status' => $row['course_status']
               );
```

I can `print_r($menu)` with all data.

How can I assign the keys and values to different variables like:

```
$status_0 = $key[0] <br>
$count_0 = $value[0] <br>
$status_1 = $key[1] <br>
$count_1 = $value[1] <br>
```

and so on...?

Thank you!

Comment: This is useless.

Comment: Can you describe better what are trying to achieve

Comment: this seems a bit pointless. $row contains meaningful field names. Your example set of variables are meaningless names. What's the end goal?

Comment: @misher if I want to know how many courses with status 3 are there. What would I do? Thanks!

Comment: You can do it in query... SELECT count(something) WHERE course_status = 3 GROUP BY course_status

Comment: array_keys, array_values, foreach loops, etc. have fun rtfm

Answer (score 0):

A little more info, perhaps pasting the code, would be helpful. If I understand it correctly, you could just change your query to:

$sql="SELECT course_status as 'status', COUNT(course_name) as 'count' FROM courses GROUP BY course_status";

Then a simple foreach loop will give you the right display.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely understanding your question.  But iterating through an array of arrays is a simple as:

```
<?php

$items = [
    [
        'foo' => 'Hello',
        'bar' => 23
    ],
    [
        'foo' => 'Earth',
        'bar' => 47
    ]
];

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item['foo'];
    echo $item['bar'];
}
```

Output:

```
Hello23Earth47
```

Further, rather than assigning to individual variables, you can access an individual item's value by targeting the appropriate key:

```
echo $items[1]['foo'];
```

Output:

```
Earth
```

To parse the array item in a string, wrap with curlies:

```
echo "{$items[0]['foo']} Dolly";
```

Output:

```
Hello Dolly
```